# How to call a swift method which parameter is a protocol from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to call a swift method which parameter is a protocol from Objective-C.

```
Class A
{
func sendMessage<Serializable: Encodable>(message:Serializable){
        let jsonData =   try! JSONEncoder().encode(message)
    
    }
}
```

Objective-C code

```
A a = [[A alloc] init];
[a sendMessage] ;// Not Available
```

How can I call this method from Objective-C.

Comment: Have you imported `TargetName-Swift.h`

Comment: I have imported it and I am able to call other methods which are having just strings as parameters.

Comment: Have you tried adding @objc in the front of the func declaration? Something like "@objc func sendMessage..."

Comment: @santhosh : Please consider accepting the answer if you think it clarified your doubt

Comment: @santhosh: Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `sendMessage` will ever appear in compiled `TargetName-Swift.h` because Generics and `Encodable` protocol is not available in `Objective-C`.

Clearly when you use

`sendMessage<Serializable: Encodable>(message:Serializable)`

You employ Generics as well as `Encodable` protocol which is only available in Swift not in Objective-C

When you try to access the `Swift` functions in your `Objective-C` files, compiler creates a `Objective-C` equivalent/ counterpart of your `Swift` functions hence you see the signature for those methods in your `TargetName-Swift.h` files.

But `Generics` and `Encodable` protocol are not available in `Objective-C` so it can't translate your Swift function using `Generics` and `Encodable` protocol to Objective-C equivalent. Hence You can never call such Swift methods from Objective-C files